# Git post-receive with gunicorn start, exit to terminal

Tags: git, bash, gunicorn

I need a bit of help, when I push to my git server I have this post-receive code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TRAGET="/var/www/app"
GIT_DIR="/opt/git/app.git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
        if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]];
        then
                echo "Reference $ref. Sending ${BRANCH} to production..."
                git --work-tree=$TRAGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
                pkill gunicorn
                cd /var/www/app
                gunicorn run:app &
                cd -
        else
                echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
        fi
done
```

It pushes correctly and does everything what it's supposed to do, but it stays in this output below, so I need to press Ctrl+C to leave it and go to terminal. I think it has to do something with gunicorn starting the server.

```
remote: [2018-01-21 03:44:05 +0200] [3023] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
remote: [2018-01-21 03:44:05 +0200] [3023] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3023)
remote: [2018-01-21 03:44:05 +0200] [3023] [INFO] Using worker: sync
remote: [2018-01-21 03:44:05 +0200] [3028] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3028
```

Can I do something with the code so it automatically goes to terminal after the push, so I don't have to press ^C to leave it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. Do you figured out how to solve?